# Laravel - Join then alias two column

Tags: sql-server, laravel

i have a sql to call my table like this :

```
$media = MediaOrder::join('users','users.nik','=','media_order.created_by')
                ->select('media_order.*','users.nickname AS nama1')
                ->where('media_order.group_id','=', auth()->user()->group_id)
                ->get();
```

And then i was using this alias to replace `nik` for column `created_by` in table `media_order` by replace it with `nickname` from table `users` like this :

```
->editColumn('created_by', function ($row) {
                        return $row->nama1;           
                      })
```

And it working, here is the result :

[image]

but then i had another column in my table that called `traffic_viewed_by` which also using `nik` column in table `media_order`, something like this :

[image]

it still using `nik` for the table and i dont know how to alias it to make it show using `nickname` from table `users` and then show it in my table, i have no clue how to do it,  anyone had an solution or maybe alternative way to do it?, any help is really appreciated, thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get another user for another column you will need to join the other user as well. And since you are joining `users` twice, they each need a unique name so SQL can understand what you are trying to do.

```
$media = MediaOrder::join('users as created_by_user','created_by_user.nik','=','media_order.created_by')
                ->join('users as viewed_by_user','viewed_by_user.nik','=','media_order.traffic_viewed_by')
                ->select('media_order.*','created_by_user.nickname AS nama1', 'viewed_by_user.nickname AS nama2')
                ->where('media_order.group_id','=', auth()->user()->group_id)
                ->get();
```

Comment: hello, the code is working perfectly thank you!, but there are some issue like, there are some NULL value in my `traffic_viewed_by`, so the table only get those row which had a value in `traffic_viewed_by`, is there a way to make those row shows up?, thanks again.

Comment: You can just add a `->whereNotNull('media_order.traffic_viewed_by')`

Comment: Here is what i've been trying but sadly it still get row which `traffic_viewed_by` not NULL, and aplogize im wrong
`$media = MediaOrder::join('users as created','created.nik','=','media_order.created_by')->join('users as viewed','viewed.nik','=','media_order.traffic_viewed_by')->select('media_order.*','created.nickname AS nama1', 'viewed.nickname AS nama2')->where('media_order.group_id','=', auth()->user()->group_id)->whereNotNull('media_order.traffic_viewed_by')->get();`

Comment: Then - is it null or an empty string you are saving in traffic_viewed_by? If the first is the case `->where('media_order.traffic_viewed_by', '!=', '')`

Comment: it was NULL when the order were created, so when the user traffic is viewed the order then the value of `nik` will be saved into `traffic_viewed_by` then it will be updated in database.

Comment: never mind that, i found out that i can use `->leftJoin`, and now the null row is being shown, thank you!.